# Is there a way to limit the number of call simultaneously redux toolkit?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I'm building a web app with `redux toolkit query`. I notice that on my landing page there are a lot of queries that gets trigger. Is there a way to tell `redux toolkit query` to execute only 2 queries at giving time. So it has to wait until one finishes to go to the next query.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll find your answer in the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the amount of concurrent executions by using [useLazyQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) and checking the amount of concurrent queries running in your store each time a new request is needed.

Let's say you have a query named `FetchData` and a [API Slice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/overview#api-slice-overview) named `FetchApi`:

```js
const [trigger, result] = useLazyFetchDataQuery();
```

The code above instantiates a trigger function and the query promise (uninitialized).

Now, before executing the trigger and initizalizing the query, we need to check for queries running inside the Redux Store:

```js
const store = UseStore();

const queriesBeingExecuted = Object.values(store.fetchApi.queries).filter(
    request => request.status === 'pending'
).length;
```

And then finally, trigger the request:

```js
const maxConcurrentQueries = 2

if (queriesBeingExecuted < maxConcurrentQueries && result.isUninitialized) {
    trigger(yourQueryArguments, true);
}
```

This will ensure that always only 2 queries will be running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the queries you want to delay, you can specify a `skip` option

```
const { data, error, status } = useYourQuery(name, {
    skip: yourCondition,
  });
```

If skip is true, the query will not trigger

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.